# НЕ передается переменная через POST?

Tags: post, php, html

есть вот такая форма

```
<form action='send_mess.php' method='post'>
<br>
<textarea cols='45' rows='4' name='message'></textarea><br>
<input type='hidden' name='iduser' value='<?php echo $myrow['id']; ?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='myid' value='<?php echo $myrow2['id']; ?>'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Отправить'>
</form>
```

Она передает переменную message - принимается в обработчике она так

```
if (isset($_POST['message'])) { $text = $_POST['message'];}//получаем текст сообщения
```

но при выводе вот такой проверки

```
if (empty($text)) {//есть ли все необходимые данные? Если нет, то останавливаем
exit ("Нельзя отправлять пустые сообщения!");}
```

она естественно выдает отричательный результат якобы форма не заполнена(( в чем дело помогиет?? у меня просто уже взгляд кажется замылился..

---

да локалка - са настраивал по инструкцие - все обычно работает, надо код переписать в ручную снова..

Comment: попробуй без емпти

    if($text)
    // и можно писать сокращено
    <?=$myrow['id']?>


Зачем два раза проверять?

Comment: написал echo $text; сразу после 
    if (isset($_POST['message'])) { $text = $_POST['message'];}
и 
    if($text)
выводит сообщение но все равно срабатывает отрицательный результат ОО выводит что поле на заполненно!!!

Comment: скопировал твой код сюда: http://wtruib.ru/test.php  толко в форме отправляю на test.php  и добавил echo $text;  все работает!

Comment: Где проверяеш? если на локалке то сам настраивал?

Comment: Все было до отупения просто в форме нашел нестыковку всем спасибо!)

Answer (score 3):

1. Вывести на экран текст из поля ввода:

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) echo $_POST['message'];
   ```
2. Посмотреть что отправляется в POST, например с помощью Firebug

... обновлено:
Проверил код у себя. Всё работает!

Comment: 1 - ничегоне выводится(
2 - тоже особо ничего у меня Хром